# How to set Assets LounchImage for LounchScreen in xcode 8.3.2

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I want to use LounchImage assets to apply LounchScreen to my application. Anyone can tell me how to set it up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS4sH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Project Navigator -> add new file. Choose Asset catalog. Then save it. 
Choose created asset catalog and below add launch image from menu:

[image]

Then go to settings remove text from field next to Launch Screen File and choose "Use Asset catalog" as launch image source.

[image]

Comment: but .. size of image .. how to set it ?

Comment: @user7845351 here you can find all sizes you need https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

use graphic editor to scale image and then add created images to asset catalog